# Horizontal Overflow appears when the file exceeds 100vh

Tags: html, css, overflow, viewport

I'm confused as to why when I exceed the 100vh, a horizontal scroll bar appears. I know you can use overflow-x: hidden; but is there a way to solve it without using that?

here's a sample code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.job-box {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 25vh;
  border-bottom: solid 1pt #000000;
}
.job-box img {
  height: 10vh;
}
.title-box {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: calibri;
}
```

```html
<div class="job-box">
  assaas
</div>
<div class="job-box">
  assaas
</div>
<div class="job-box">
  assaas
</div>
<div class="job-box">
  assaas
</div>
```

When you remove the last div, the horizontal scrollbar disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect you're describing is the result of the *VERTICAL SCROLLBAR* taking space on the side of the page, and in order to maintain the width of the `<div>`s, you get a *HORIZONTAL SCROLLBAR*.

If you use a with of 100% instead, you won't have this problem:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.job-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 25vh;
  border-bottom: solid 1pt #000000;
}
.job-box img {
  height: 10vh;
}
.title-box {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: calibri;
}
```

```html
<div class="job-box">
  assaas
</div>
<div class="job-box">
  assaas
</div>
<div class="job-box">
  assaas
</div>
<div class="job-box">
  assaas
</div>
```

Comment: I never realized that scrollbars are part of the viewport. Thanks for this!